# Blockchain.info transaction unconfirmed for several days

Tags: blockchain.info

I [swept a paperwallet to blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/tx/e34097f257af3f91b7874f33ad0b4bb2f5980d35ba6f8e7ca38148c084d4656c) and the transaction has been unconfirmed for several days...it looks like it was sent in multiple tiny transactions. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

https://blockchain.info/tx/e34097f257af3f91b7874f33ad0b4bb2f5980d35ba6f8e7ca38148c084d4656c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. Your paper wallet consisted of lots of small transactions inbound, and now you are sweeping them to a new address. A wallet is a collection of unspent outputs.

The transaction looks fine, and the txfee is standard. Given that the network is under a spam attack of sorts right now, its possible that the fee is simply not high enough to confirm. It may take a while under the current circumstances until it does.